# Pandas Dataframe Integer Column Data Cleanup

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a CSV file, which I read through pandas `read_csv` module.

There is one column, which is supposed to have `numbers only`, but the data has some bad values.

Some rows (very few) have "alphanumeric" strings, few rows are empty while a few others have floating point numbers. Also, for some reason, some numbers are also being read as strings.

I want to convert it in the following way:

1. Alphanumeric, None, empty (numpy.nan) should be converted to `0`
2. Floating point should be typecasted to `int`
3. Integers should remain as they are
4. And obvs, numbers should be read as numbers only.

How should I proceed, as I have no other idea than to read each row one by one and typecast into `int`, in a try-except block, while assigning `0` if exception is raised.

like:

```
def typecast_int(n):
    try:
        return int(n)
    except:
        return 0

for idx, row in df.iterrows:
    row["number_column"] = typecast_int(row["number_column"])
```

But there are some issues with this approach. Firstly, `iterrows` is bad performance wise. And my dataframe may have upto 700k to 1M records and I have to process ~500 such CSV files. And secondly, it just doesn't feel right to do it this way.

I could do a tad better by using `df.apply` instead of `iterrows` but that is also not too different.

Comment: Have you tried providing `dtype` or `converters` option on loading the file?

Comment: I did not, but I think that would cause exception if I give dtype as int, due to alphanumeric values @JanWilamowski

Comment: You could handle that with `error_bad_lines=False` but using a converter is probably the better way

Comment: So, with the option `dtype=int`, I can use `error_bad_lines=False` or `on_bad_lines=skip`. Let me try that!!

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly but what about `df.number_column = pd.to_numeric(df.number_column, errors="coerce").fillna(0).astype(int)`? This first forces this column to be numeric values only. If errors arise (e.g., due to alphanumeric) they got "coerce"d to NaN. Then we fill those NaN's with 0 and lastly cast everything to integers.

Comment: @JanWilamowski It is causing exception due to `nan` values at time of reading CSV. If there is any improvement you can propose, I think it will be simplest way to solve this.
@MustafaAydın let me try your method.

Comment: @MustafaAydın Your method works. If you post that as the answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your 4 conditions, there's

```py
df.number_column = (pd.to_numeric(df.number_column, errors="coerce")
                         .fillna(0)
                         .astype(int))
```

This first converts the column to be numeric values only. If errors arise (e.g., due to alphanumerics) they got "coerce"d to NaN. Then we fill those NaN's with 0 and lastly cast everything to integers.